# How to perform a NOT query with postgres_ext

Tags: ruby, postgresql, postgres-ext

Is it possible to perform a NOT type query with chained methods using postgres_ext?

```
rules = Rule.where.overlap(:tags => ["foo"])
```

Basically want the inverse of the above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In regular active record you can use `.where.not` as described in this article: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activerecords-wherenot however looking through the source code of postgres_ext I don't know if it is defined in that library. You may be able to construct your query in a way that uses the native active record methods.